# FTP докачка файлов

Tags: ftp, java

Реализую на java закачку файлов на FTP-сервер и соответственно докачку, если вдруг соединение было оборвано. Вот [лог](http://zalil.ru/33046171) с FTP сервера. STOR The.mp4 отправляет файл,
затем обрывается связь, и быстро восстанавливается, до того как пройдет таймаут (минуты 2)
С повторной отправкой вываливается ошибка:

> 550 can't access file

Получается в таком случае? мы никак не сможем дописать файл и нужно ждать, когда то соединение прекратиться? Есть ли возможность это обойти?

Comment: Не вижу таких вариантов. Подождите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто отозвался, получилось решить задачу. Расскажу что да как. Приложение для андроида, в главном активити выбираю, что скачать, а дальше, как только появляется wifi соединение с сервером, запускается сервис, который пытается отправить и скачать файлы. Итого, добавил перед подключением

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverURL,21,myURL,prevPort);
socket.close();
```

Т.е просто создаю сокет, где prevPort - порт, который я считал в предыдущий раз с помощью библиотеки common-net от apache

```
ftp.getLocalPort();
```

и закрываю его.
Такая схема работает, соединение закрывается и можно отправлять файл.

Comment: Что у Вас и выпытывали целый день.

Answer (score 2):

Java здесь походу не причем. Надо дать права на модификацию каталога FTP юзеру System - [пруфлинк сюда](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5559)

Comment: Не понял причем тут юзер System? А права на изменения моему пользователю даны, но он не может записать файл, так как сервер ещё ждет от него ответа и не даёт обратиться к файлу.

Comment: Дискуссию прочти по линку

Comment: По ссылке я естественно прочитал) Может я не правильно понял. У него два компьютера, на одном Filezilla стоит на другом расшареная папка. И он пытается записать на неё файл? Так? Если да, то у меня другая ситуация.

Comment: Посмотрел лог. Хочу уточнить. 

@imholynx, как Вы думаете, при обрыве связи соединение в  Passive Mode   c 192.168.0.156 , по которому послали STOR The.mp4 разорвалось ? Или нет, но по какой-то причине процесс установивший это соединение перестал передавать данные, но close не делал ?

Если можно про архитектуру Вашей системы поподробнее.

Comment: Разрабатывается приложение, которое должно учитывать обрывы в связи.  Во время первой передачи The.mp4 обрывается соединение(соответсвенно close не может пройти) и сразу восстанавливается. Сервер не закрывает соединение и ждёт 2 минуты таймаута. В это время программа снова пытается передать файл, но не может, так как сервер, заблокировал его изменения и ждёт сигнала от предыдущего соединения.

Comment: Если правильно понял, Вы физически разрываете сеть, а потом снова включаете кабель ?

Процесс на 192.168.0.156 что делает в это время ? Обычно если ничего не делать, такие вещи вообще незаметны.

И еще важный вопрос - ОС на узлах какие ? И клиент на Java это что ? Standalone или из под какого-то сервера (Tomcat ?).

Comment: Боюсь, что они незаметны для сервера. А клиент успевает узнать о падении интерфейса. Со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: Боюсь дело в другом. Для ОС (обеих) это незаметно. Клиент, боюсь, работает с соединением не на прямую, а через некий сервис, который держит пул соединений (или что-то в этом духе). 

Короче реально shutdown() на сокет на стороне клиента никто не делает. 

Но, это все предположения.

Поэтому-то я и хочу деталей архитектуры добиться от автора.

Answer (score 1):

вот пример простой докачки файла 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Tiny-Application/FileDownloadManager.htm

Comment: Докачка у меня реализована. Все работает, если повторное закачивание на сервер начинается по прошествии таймаута. Иначе сервер не даёт повторно залить файл, так как предыдущее соединение открыто и по нему может быть изменен файл. С точки зрения сервера все правильно. Может есть вариант после соединения, через тот же порт что и в прошлый раз послать сообщение на отключение?

Comment: @imholynx Это уже интересно. Через тот же порт (какой?). В той же последовательности numb/acq (см. tcp). И как это реализовать?

Другими словами -- сымитировать только что разорванное (со стороны клиента) соединение. Вот так и пополняются ряды кибервзломщиков.